# DatePicker dialog doesn't work on iPhone 12 or greater

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gluon, gluon-mobile, gluonfx

With iPhone 12 or higher, the DatePicker window blocks its execution when the showAndWait method is called, without showing exceptions and without opening its dialog.
In addition, it is no longer possible to go back but you must necessarily close the app

https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/6.0.6/com.gluonhq.charm.glisten/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/DatePicker.html

Comment: Post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and logs.

Comment: @JoséPereda In the following link on gitHub, I have attached the run with an iPhone12 and the code of the test project on which it was run. As mentioned, clicking on the central button that should open the calendar, the app freezes and I can do nothing but close it.  https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-gradle-plugin/issues/156